# How do I Filter a viewlist based on a selection made on a createview form? Django

Tags: python, html, json, django

I am learning how to use Python & Django. I don't have much experience, and this has been a huge learning process for me. Please forgive any ignorance in my question.

I am designing a Django app and have a few relational tables created. My question involves only my first 2 models/forms/views.

Here are my models
`

```
class CustomerName(models.Model):
    #Fields
    company = models.CharField(max_length = 60, help_text = "Enter Customer Name",unique=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.company

class ProgramName(models.Model):
    #Fields
    customer = models.ForeignKey("CustomerName",on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    program = models.CharField(max_length = 60, help_text = "Enter Program Name")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.program
```

`
Here are my Views (Ive left out the customer add view since that works and I don't think its relevant)

`

```
class ProgramAddView(CreateView, ListView):
    template_name = 'app/ProgramAdd.html'
    form_class = Programform
    model = ProgramName
    success_url = reverse_lazy('Part Number Add')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["qs_json"] = json.dumps(list(ProgramName.objects.values()))
        return context
```

`
Here is the form

`

class Programform(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
model = ProgramName
fields = "**all**"

```
class Customerform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomerName
        fields = ('company',)
```

`

Here is the HTML app/ProgramAdd.html
`

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <h2>Program</h2>
  <form method="post" class = 'formarea'>
  <div id = 'formarea' class = 'formdiv'>
    {{ form.media.js }}
     <table>
      {{ form.as_table }}
    </table>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
    <a href="{% url 'HomePage' %}">Nevermind</a>
  </div>
  </form>
  <h2>Program List</h2>
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Program</th>
            <th scope="col">Customer</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
  <ul>
    <div id="box">
      <!-- Iterate over object_list -->
      {% for item in object_list %}
      <!-- Display Objects -->
        {{ item }}
    </div>
   
    <hr/>
    <!-- If object_list is empty  -->
    {% empty %}
    <li>No objects yet.</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

{% endblock %}

{% block scripts %}
<script>
    const data = '{{qs_json}}'
    console.log(data)

    const rdata = JSON.parse(data.replace(/&quot;/g, '"'))
    console.log(rdata)
    console.log("WHAT!?")

    const input = document.getElementById('id_customer')
    console.log(input.selected)

    let filteredArr = []

    input.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
        console.log(input.value)
        box.innerHTML = ""
        filteredArr = rdata.filter(programname=> programname['program'].includes(e.target.value))
        console.log(filteredArr)
        if (filteredArr.length > 0){
            filteredArr.map(programname=>{
                box.innerHTML += `<b>${programname['program']}</b><br>`
                box.innerHTML += `<b>${programname['customer_id']}</b><br>`
            })
        } else {
            box.innerHTML = "<b>No results found...</b>"
        }
    })

</script>
{% endblock scripts %}
```

`

Here is how the page looks
[image: Example 1]

Now ideally, you would be filling out the form to add a program to the customer in the database. I wanted to display existing Customers + programs already in the database down below the form.

When I make a choice though, this always happens
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbuEO.png)

There are 2 questions/issues I have so far that I've yet to find a solution for.

Question A. I need to filter my list by Customer name instead of program name but any time I reference the customer column (Example down below) I am told I cant use .includes as its not an array?

*This returns the following error: programname.customer_id.includes is not a function
`filteredArr = rdata.filter(programname=> programname['customer_id'].includes(e.target.value))`

This confuses me as console.log(rdata) returns this table
0
:
{id: 1, customer_id: 1, program: 'Program A'}
1
:
{id: 2, customer_id: 2, program: 'Program A'}
2
:
{id: 3, customer_id: 2, program: 'Program B'}

which I would assume means I can filter by customer_id instead?
I also ran console.log(input.value) and it returns either 1 or 2 or 3 based on my customer selection? so that would mean the filter should be basing its test on the value of the proper drop down box.

Question B:
My second question, how do I display customer as its name rather than ID number?

I appreciate any feedback or guidance. Thank you for your time.

For question A:
I tried swapping out
`filteredArr = rdata.filter(programname=> programname['program'].includes(e.target.value))`
to both
`filteredArr = rdata.filter(programname=> programname['customer_id'].includes(e.target.value))`
as well as
`filteredArr = rdata.filter(customername=> customername['company'].includes(e.target.value))`
But I either get undefined or programname.customer_id.includes is not a function

I have also extensively googled into the issue and could not find anything that did not involve my specific request of a create view + a list view working together.

For question B:
Instead of
`

```
{% for item in object_list %}
      <!-- Display Objects -->
        {{ item }}
```

`I tried using`

```
{% for object in object_list %}
      <!-- Display Objects -->
        {{ object.company }}
        {{ object.program }}
```

`
Which seems to show the desired result but this does not work with the filter at all. So I cannot proceed with this option.

Answer (score 1):

After messing around with it longer, I was able to achieve near my goal using

filteredArr = rdata.filter(programname=> programname.customer_id == input.value)